# How to add items to List inside inner anonymous class (FireBase OnCompleteListener) in Java

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Using FireBaseFireStore I tried to extract some data from collections (here you can see them as Constants.KEY_COLLECTION_USERS), which are located inside various items of collection Constants.KEY_COLLECTION_COFFEE_SHOPS. However, in result I get an empty List users, which should be filled with items to display.

```
database.collection(Constants.KEY_COLLECTION_COFFEE_SHOPS)
    .whereEqualTo("activated", true)
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(task->{
        if(task.isSuccessful()&&task.getResult()!=null) {
           List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot queryDocumentSnapshot : task.getResult()) {
                if(2>queryDocumentSnapshot.getDouble("parameter1"){

                    database.collection(Constants.KEY_COLLECTION_COFFEE_SHOPS)
                            .document(queryDocumentSnapshot.getId())
                            .collection(Constants.KEY_COLLECTION_USERS)
                            .whereEqualTo("status", "active")
                            .get()
                            .addOnCompleteListener(task2 -> {
                                if(task2.isSuccessful()&&task2.getResult()!=null){
                                    for(QueryDocumentSnapshot queryDocumentSnapshot2 : task2.getResult()){
                                        if (queryDocumentSnapshot2.getLong("parameter2">2) {
                                            User user = new User();
                                            user.id=queryDocumentSnapshot2.getString(Constants.KEY_USER_ID);
                                            user.name=queryDocumentSnapshot2.getString(Constants.KEY_NAME);
                                            user.image=queryDocumentSnapshot2.getString(Constants.KEY_IMAGE);
                                            user.age=queryDocumentSnapshot2.getLong(Constants.KEY_AGE).toString();
                                            users.add(user);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }
            }
            makeToast(users.size()+"");
                    if (users.size()>0) {
                        UserAdapter userAdapter = new UserAdapter(users, this);
                        binding.usersRecycleView.setAdapter(userAdapter);
                    }
        }});
    }
```

I tried to put this Inside the second addOnCompleteListener:

```
UserAdapter userAdapter = new UserAdapter(users, this);
binding.usersRecycleView.setAdapter(userAdapter);
```

It worked, but only for one item of `Constants.KEY_COLLECTION_COFFEE_SHOPS` as you can understand. I also tried to make users a static variable, but it didn't help.

Can you suggest any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to move `makeToast(users.size()+"")` right after where the second for loop ends? Does it work that way?